Can we define inputs globally across different triggers in Github workflows?
Do GitHub Actions support a way to define inputs globally across different triggers. Or should each trigger must define its own set of inputs?
I need to give same set of inputs for both workflow_call and workflow_dispatch. Is that possible?
In my workflow file, Both workflow_call and workflow_dispatch define the same input parameter X. It is a boolean that defaults to false and is required to be specified when the workflow is invoked, either by another workflow or manually. So instead of writing like below:
workflow_call:
inputs:
  X:
    description: ' '
    required: true
    type: boolean
    default: false


workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      X:
        description: ' '
        required: true
        type: boolean
        default: false

Can i define inputs globally across different triggers so that i only need to specify input once?
That is Is it possible to avoid duplication of inputs in workflow_call and workflow_dispatch? Can we use shared_inputs between workflow_call and workflow_dispatch ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Thanks for replying. I have edited the Question

No, you can't define "global" inputs. You have to repeat the input definitions in different triggers.
